# Conditional Entropy is less than entropy

Tags: probability

Let $p_{ij}=P(X=i,Y=j)$ be the joint distribution, $P(X=i)=p_i=\sum_j p_{ij}, P(Y=j)=q_j=\sum_i p_{ij}$ be the marginal distributions, and $p_{i|j}=\frac{p_{ij}}{q_j}$ be the conditional distribution. Then the conditional entropy is defined as $$E[h(X|Y)]=-\sum_j \sum_i p_{i|j} \ln p_{i|j} q_j $$ Show $E[h(X|Y)]\leq h(X)$ where $h(X)$ is the entropy of $X$. I'm at a lost as to even know where to begin.

Comment: Check if this recent [post #69859](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69859/relative-entropy-is-non-negative) is of interest...

Comment: They're similar, but that post deals with relative entropy and this is conditional.

Comment: It is called "information can’t hurt".

Answer (score 9):

First, you give an incorrect definition for $\mathbb{E}(h(X|Y))$. It [should](http://octavia.zoology.washington.edu/teaching/429/lecturenotes/Lecture3.pdf) instead read as follows:
$$
   \mathbb{E}(h(X|Y)) = - \sum_j q_j \sum_i p_{i|j} \ln p_{i|j}
$$

Define relative information $I(X, Y) = H(X) - \mathbb{E}(h(X|Y))$. Then 
$$I(X,Y) = - \sum_i p_i \ln(p_i) + \sum_{j,i} p_{i|j} q_j \ln p_{i|j} =  - \sum_{i,j} p_{i,j} \ln(p_i) + \sum_{j,i} p_{i,j} \ln p_{i|j}
$$
hence
$$
I(X,Y) = \sum_{i,j} p_{i,j} \ln \frac{p_{i,j}}{p_i q_j}
$$
The function $\varphi(x) = x \ln(x)$ is convex for $x>0$. Thus, using Jensen's inequality:

$$
  I(X,Y) = \sum_{i,j} p_i q_j \cdot \varphi\left( \frac{p_{i,j}}{p_i q_j} \right) \ge \varphi\left( \sum_{i,j} p_i q_j \cdot \frac{p_{i,j}}{p_i q_j} \right) = \varphi(1) = 0
$$

Comment: It is noteworthy that in order to invoke Jensen's inequality, the coefficients must sum up to 1. This is true in this case since $\sum_{i,j} p_iq_i = \sum_i p_i \sum_j q_j = 1$.