# $I[X,Y] :=- \sum_{x,y} p(x,y)\ln{p(x,y)}$, Show that $I[X, Y] \le I[X]+I[Y]$

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

Let $x,y$ be stochastic variables and $p$ be a probability measure.

$I[X,Y] :=- \sum_{x,y} p(x,y)\ln{p(x,y)}$ with $p(x,y) := P(X=x, Y=y)$

I have to show that $I[X,
Y] \le I[X]+I[Y]$

I mustn't assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. My problem is how to write $p(x,y)$ into $p(x)$ and $p(y)$.

Any tipps or ideas on how to separate the p(x,y) and show the inequality? Thanks in advance!

[Conditional Entropy is less than entropy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70136/conditional-entropy-is-less-than-entropy) is similar, but it doesn't fully answer my question (their definition of $I$ is different: over there: $I[X,Y] = \sum_{x,y} p(x,y) \ln \frac{{p(x,y)}}{p(x)p(y)}$

Comment: I tried to write $p(x,y)=p(x)p(y \mid x)$ but since $p(y \mid x)$ is definded via $p(x,y)/p(x)$ that doesn't bring me anywhere

Comment: Do you know the [chain rule for entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy#Chain_rule)? This is a direct consequence of that, and the fact that conditioning reduces entropy.

Comment: Starting from the formula which you say "does not fully answer" your question, note that $$\sum_{x,y}p(x,y)\ln\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)p(y)}$$ is $$\sum_{x,y}p(x,y)\ln p(x,y)-\sum_x\left(\sum_yp(x,y)\right)\ln p(x)-\sum_y\left(\sum_xp(x,y)\right)\ln p(y)$$ which is $$\sum_{x,y}p(x,y)\ln p(x,y)-\sum_xp(x)\ln p(x)-\sum_yp(y)\ln p(y)$$ hence, in the end, this formula does fully answer your question.

Comment: ah, ok thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

By the [chain rule for entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy#Chain_rule), $$ I[X,Y] = I[X] + I[Y|X] $$

[Conditioning reduces entropy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70136/conditional-entropy-is-less-than-entropy), so $$ I[Y|X] \leq I[Y] $$

Thus, $$ I[X,Y] \leq I[X] + I[Y] $$

Comment: This is considering as known an equivalent version of the desired result, is it not?

Comment: @Did Ah, yes. I meant to include a link to the other post about conditioning in my answer.

Comment: Link or no link, I find odd to state that A holds because B holds when A and B are basically different formulations of the same result and when there is no reason to expect that B would be well known while A would not. In the present case, if I was forced to decide which came first of the egg and the hen, I might elect A as being the base result and B as being a consequence of A, not the opposite as your answer posits.

Comment: @Did In general, sure. However, if I am asked to demonstrate A, and the asker acknowledges an equivalent statement B without recognising the equivalence, pointing out that they are equivalent is an answer, is it not?

Comment: I missed where the OP ackowledged B. Actually they rejected B as being irrelevant to A, didn't they?

Comment: I missed where the OP rejected B as being irrelevant to A. Actually they admitted that B was similar to A, didn't they?

Comment: On a less facetious note, I am happy to delete my answer if it is actively unhelpful.

Comment: Quote: "Conditional Entropy is less than entropy (the question) is similar, but it doesn't fully answer my question".